# How to keep function called with python ctypes running

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, ctypes, sparkle

I'm trying to create a minimal python script that calls the winsparkle C library using ctypes. The code only works if I run it line-by-line, `win_sparkle_check_update_without_ui()` pops up a window to download an update as expected. But running the script normally this function just gets called and skipped instantly, it doesn't remain open, unless I add the hacky time.sleep option.

What is the proper pythonic way to run this function and leave it open until the user closes the popup?

```
from ctypes import CDLL
import logging, time

class UpdateAgent(object):

    def __init__(self, appcast_url):

        self.appcast_url = appcast_url

    def check_for_update(self):

        winsparkle = CDLL("WinSparkle.dll")

        url = self.appcast_url

        winsparkle.win_sparkle_set_appcast_url(url.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

        winsparkle.win_sparkle_set_app_details(
                                unicode('Company'),
                                unicode('myapp'),
                                unicode(9))

        winsparkle.win_sparkle_init()

        winsparkle.win_sparkle_check_update_without_ui()

        #time.sleep(10)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.check_for_update()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info('%s' % (e))
```

Comment: No solution to this? Running into the same issue...

Comment: My solution was to roll my own code. Download an update and run it. To keep winsparkle open, you need a parent UI to attach it to